# Mod Rewrite routing params to link

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Now in my web app I have links like:

**www.page.com/index.php?p=menuitem1**

**www.page.com/index.php?p=menuitem2**

etc.

I need to rewrite this links in format like:

**www.page.com/menuitem1**

**www.page.com/menuitem2**

How to do it by single mod_rewrite command?

Comment: Sorry. First it is unclear what you ask: What are those result formats you wrote meant to be? What should be called. apart from that: you forgot to post your attempts so far. Please do so, you will get much better and faster replies. you should not be lazy and not try yourself at all and just expect others to do your work for you...

Comment: How to do it by single mod_rewrite command? You need to implement a pattern called Front Controller + Router + Dispatcher + PSR-0 autoloader. Any framework has it in the box.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(menuitem1|menuitem2)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```